# Defining a preprocessor directive for windows 7

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, preprocessor-directive

I am making use of SetDllDirectory() and wants to know how can i define a directive for windows 7 HP 64 bit i am thinking something like this :

In preprocessor directives :

```
 Add WIN7
```

In the .cpp i was thinking to add something like

```
#ifndef WIN7<- where the function is used
SetDllDirectory();
#endif
```

but as soon as i add the statements the SetDllDirectory becomes commented.

And this is something i tried with , i added **WIN7** in the preprocessor definations and added :

```
#if defined(__WIN7__)
if (regkeyExists) {
    if (regkey->HasValue("LibPath")) {
        regkey->QueryValue("LibPath", value);
        if (!value.empty()) {
            wxSetEnv("ABCLib", value);
            SetDllDirectory(value.c_str());
        }
    }

}
SetDllDirectory("C:\\Program Files\\ABC\\ABCProject\\lib");
#endif
```

Is this the right to declare windows 7

Thanks

Comment: `SetDllDirectory becomes commented.` What exactly do you mean

Comment: SetDllDirectory () lost its existence , actually i am using the # statements inside the code

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to define your own macro to detect Windows 7, use the [ones provided by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - wrap your Win7 only code in:

```
#ifdef _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 
xyz()
#endif
```

If you do create your own, you must define it when you want to compile for Windows 7, it seems that you're hiding the SelDllDirectory() function - #ifndef means "if not defined" so if WIN7 macro is not defined anywhere, then you get that function.

Comment: I have tried this thing as u said putting the code within the ifdef's does it mean to put the whole source file into it ?

Comment: @LindaHarrison - you need a beginner's guide to the C preprocessor. http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx9c.html

Answer (score 1):

How about [`NTDDI_VERSION` or `_WIN32_WINNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?